# remove black background when switching tab of `UITabBarController`

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have `UITabBarController` having 4 tabs. inside the first tab's ViewController i presented Popup using `popUpVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`

so i got this(thats perfect as i want):
[image]

but now when i switch to `secondTab` **Dollor_Icon**, and then immediately come back to `firstTab`... i get the blackBG instead of transparent BG.
like this:
[image]

my code of modal presentation:

```
let popUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUp")
popUpVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(popUpVC, animated: true)
```

Hope to get rid of that black background and why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the entire code where you have set the presentation over context?

Comment: question Updeted @RizwanAhmed

Comment: Did you try presenting over navigation controller. Like self.navigationcontroller.present(popUpVc,animated:true)

Comment: not working @RizwanAhmed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your firstTabViewController `ViewDidLoad()` method:

```
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

Hope, your problem being fixed.

For more details on `definesPresentationContext` see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext'